# Getting:UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I asked my friend for help writing this code for me, since i know nothing about python. 
He wrote it on a Mac and now i'm trying to troubleshoot on my win10... 
I'm trying to solve this error. Any idea where i should change?

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0eb0b0fb56f4> in <module>
     13         newline = ','.join([reg_cat, reg_num, address, company]) + '\n'
     14         with open(csv_file, 'a') as f:
---> 15             f.write(newline)

c:\users\peggy\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Try changing the encoding. Change this line `with open(csv_file, 'a') as f:` to `with open(csv_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the required permissions and then encode

```
fi = open('file_name','ab')
fi.write('your text or file'.encode())
fi.close()
```